# Run Iphone app in simulator from the terminal : how to set up iPhoneSim?

Tags: command-line, terminal, ios-simulator

I found this project which seems to make it possible to run an iPhone app from command line !

http://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim

Unfortunately there is almost no documentation and i'm stuck at building this project :

- I download all sources
- I run MakeFile and i get these errors :

admin$ ./Makefile

./Makefile: line 4: -Werror: command not found

./Makefile: line 5: AppKit: command not found

./Makefile: line 6: Source/main.o: No such file or directory

./Makefile: line 11: .SUFFIXES:: command not found

./Makefile: line 12: .m.o:: command not found

./Makefile: line 13: -o: No such file or directory

./Makefile: line 15: all:: command not found

./Makefile: line 17: iphonesim:: command not found gcc-4.2: argument to '-o' is missing

./Makefile: line 20: clean:: command not found

As anybody been able to build and use this project ?

Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: Ok i admit i really suck with unix and makefile, i just don't really know what to do (everyone has to be a beginner at some point...) :

From what i see in the errors gcc complains because it cannot find .o files (arent they linker files supposed to be generated by GCC ?)

Please i just need some help on a very basic problem i guess...

Answer (score 0):

Makefile is not a program or a script.  Run 'make' to build the iphonesim program.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i found the answer, makeFile is a conf file, make is the command :

make
gcc -Wall -Werror -I. -ISource -c Source/main.m -o Source/main.o
gcc -Wall -Werror -I. -ISource -c Source/nsprintf.m -o Source/nsprintf.o
cc1obj: warnings being treated as errors
Source/nsprintf.m: In function ‘nsvfprintf’:
Source/nsprintf.m:12: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
make: *** [Source/nsprintf.o] Error 1

To resolve the warning treated as an error, edit the makeFile and remove -Werror from this line :

CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -I. -ISource